# Amazon RDS Postgresql adding new extensions

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.4

I want to download [jsonbx](http://www.pgxn.org/dist/jsonbx/1.0.0/) to RDS instance. [RDS PostgreSQL Features Supported](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/) shows only built-in features. Does this mean there is no way we can install an extension to RDS which is not in the [Feature Matrix](http://www.postgresql.org/about/featurematrix/)? Is there a work around for this?

Comment: You can't add your own extensions to RDS, at least not ones that require superuser rights (like anything with C code). This is one of the downsides you accept in exchange for convenient management.

Comment: @CraigRinger Can I add the extensions features as functions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't add your own extensions to RDS, at least not ones that require superuser rights (like anything with C code). This is one of the downsides you accept in exchange for convenient management.

If the extension only includes simple plpgsql and sql functions you can add the functions manually. That is not possible with anything requiring superuser privileges, including any extension with C code.

[jsonbx](http://www.pgxn.org/dist/jsonbx/1.0.0/) adds functions and operators. [The source contains C code](http://api.pgxn.org/src/jsonbx/jsonbx-1.0.0/), so there is no way you can load this on RDS. Ever. At all. RDS doesn't allow you to run anything that might give you superuser access or access to the underlying VM that PostgreSQL runs on, nor does it provide a way to upload extensions even if it would permit you to load them.

You will need to switch to running a standalone PostgreSQL server (say, on EC2), persuade Amazon support to make the extension available as part of their supported set of extensions, or make do without.

Answer (score 16):

Currently there are a few available extensions in [Amazon RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html) -- detailed in the "Database Engine Features" chapter.

You can issue the following command to get the available extensions supported:

```sql
SHOW rds.extensions;
```

Comment: Oh, it actually had the one i was looking for. Lucky me

Comment: @DenLilleMand They use to update the list often, so you may refresh time to time to see if there are new contribs added that might be for your interest.

Comment: You can also see the list of extensions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts

Comment: The list of extensions is now found on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/PostgreSQLReleaseNotes/postgresql-extensions.html